# Applying the Bursa-Wolf transformation

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84

I want to transform Gauss-Kruger coordinates into WGS84 coordinates by applying the Bursa-Wolf transformation. I know the Bursa-Wolf parameters for the desired transformation. What confuses me is that the [Bursa-Wolf formula](https://sis.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/sis/referencing/datum/BursaWolfParameters.html) expects 3D coordinates (`X`, `Y`, `Z`), whereas my input Gauss-Kruger coordinates are only 2D (`northing`, `easting`), and my output WGS84 coordinates are also only 2D (`latitude`, `longitude`). How do I map my 2D input/output coordinates to the 3D coordinates in the Bursa-Wolf formula?

Comment: I would guess that you need to map Z to zero.

Comment: @user30184 No, that does not yield meaningful values.

Comment: Basically, you transform lat/lon of the source CRS to a XYZ-coordinate system centered on the earth center, then apply the shifts and rotations on/around all three axis, finally reproject back to lat/lon of the target CRS. You get slightly different results if you include the height above the geoid in your calculation.

Comment: @AndreJ Correction, Bursa-Wolf/coordinate frame/position vector Z is from height above ellipsoid unless you also have geoid models or other conversions for the z values.

Comment: @user30184 you map the ellipsoidal height (h) to zero, then convert the lat-lon-h to XYZ values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Helmert-transformation (with Bursa-Wolf parameter) with geographic coordinates. First transform the geographic coordinates into geocentric coordinates. [see](https://sis.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/sis/referencing/operation/transform/EllipsoidToCentricTransform.html)

That's 3D coordinates, so you can easily integrate the altitude value.

But consider the precision using this transformation is 1 to 8 m depending on area and parameters.

But why the altitude value is the difference to NN ?

Comment: `But consider the precision using this transformation is 1 to 8 m depending on area and parameters.` Well, can you propose a better transformation than Bursa-Wolf? `But why the altitude value is the difference to NN ?` What do you mean by that?

Comment: The better way is, for example is ntv2, but you need gridshift grid file for that and it could be slow. 
Bursa-Wolf Parameter are available, the precision is ok for map visualisation. For small areas the precision is better then 1m.

Comment: Sorry MAMSL/AMSL is the right acronym. NN is a old acronym for standard zero. If you are not changing the Elevation model why calculating a new altitude value. If you change the Elevation model, there are special transformations for vertical value systems.